# Can't dismiss Google Calendar reminders

Tags: thunderbird, lightning

I'm using Thunderbird with Lightning and can't dismiss Google Calendar reminders. I click on dismiss and nothing happens.

Calendar is not read-only.

I've got this kind of errors in "Error Console"

```
[calGoogleCalendar] Modifying item xxxxxx failed:2147500037: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar issue reported in [another question](https://superuser.com/q/1207195/483696). There are a couple of things there you may want to try.

- Ignore reminders for that calendar (if it is an option for you)
- Clear the cached data if your issue is about a Exchange calendar

Comment: The workaround described there helped. Thanks @manuelvigarcia